# I'm trying to make a simple story maker but I'm stuck on the gender part

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

Im trying to make a simple story that contains users input, but i can't get my gender part to work. I want it to be able to recognize the gender from the input and then print the appropriate pronoun.

```
import time
print("What's your name?")
character_name = input("Type it in here: ")
print("How old are you?")
character_age = input("Type your age in here here: ")
def isMale():
    Male = input("You're a male? True or False?")
    if (Male == "True"):
        Male_Bool = True
    elif (Male == "False"):
        Male_Bool = False
    if (Male_Bool) == True:
        print("There was a man named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("he was " + character_age + ".")
        print("He likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")
    elif(not Male_Bool) == False:
        print("There was a woman named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("she was " + character_age + ".")
        print("She likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")
    return isMale()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: (not False) is not equal to False; it is equal to True

Comment: Your `isMale` function is never called.Also, you probably don't want to call it recursively, so you'd better strip that `return isMale()` wich will end in a endless call for your function.

Comment: Why aren't you handling your logic inside `Male == "True"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something like this that you are looking for.

```
import time
print("What's your name?")
character_name = input("Type it in here: ")
print("How old are you?")
character_age = input("Type your age in here here: ")
def isMale():
    Male = input("You're a male? True or False?")
    if (Male == "True"):
        Male_Bool = True
    elif (Male == "False"):
        Male_Bool = False
    if (Male_Bool) == True:
        print("There was a man named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("he was " + character_age + ".")
        print("He likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")
    #Check if Male_Bool is False
    elif(Male_Bool) == False:
        print("There was a woman named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("she was " + character_age + ".")
        print("She likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")
    return 
#Call the function
isMale()
time.sleep(10)
```

Also have a look at your code restructured.

```
import time

def isMale():
    Male = input("You're a male? True or False?")
    if (Male == "True"):
        Male_bool = True
    else:
        Male_bool = False
    return Male_bool

character_name = input("What's your name?")
character_age = input("How old are you?")
male = isMale()
if male:
    print(f"There was a man named {character_name},")
    print(f"he was {character_age}.")
    print(f"He likes the name {character_name},")
    print(f"but didn't like being {character_age}.")
else:
    print(f"There was a woman named {character_name},")
    print(f"she was {character_age}.")
    print(f"She likes the name {character_name},")
    print(f"but didn't like being {character_age}.")

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, kind stranger, I started learning python recently so I'm fairly new. It worked!

Comment: While your code answers the question, you didn't really explain why the original code was wrong (you added two comments, but they only state what the code is doing, not why). It would be good adding an explanation of why your solution works.

Comment: You are right. I think the root of the problems can easily be identified using the comments. They are basic Python principles...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why does your function returns itself? And why are you not calling it all? You've just defined a function, wrote it, but then, you are not doing anything with it.

Add

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    isMale()
```

at the bottom. And it will call your function.

Also, it's unnecesary to compare bool to True/False. Just write:

```
if Male_Bool:
```

The

```
elif (not Male_Bool) == False:
```

is wrong. If you choose male, so the Male_Bool will be set to False, this elif would evaluate to (not False) == False. It would never run. Just replace it with else if you have only male/female options.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first we need to understand the problem , you wrote the code and its working just have a struggle with how function works . let me explain you the structure .

```
def functionName(arguments):
   process
return output
```

so when we finished writing our function
now we have to call it to run
like this

```
functionName(args)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! I didn't know that I had to call it after I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all u are not calling the `isMale()` functon in your program, and second in the line `elif(not Male_Bool) == False:` u're are negating a attribute with a "False" value, making him equal to True. For the last, i didn't understand what u want to return, i would recommend that u remove the return line.

```
import time
print("What's your name?")
character_name = input("Type it in here: ")
print("How old are you?")
character_age = input("Type your age in here here: ")
def isMale():
    Male = input("You're a male? True or False?")
    if (Male == "True"):
        Male_Bool = True
    elif (Male == "False"):
        Male_Bool = False
    if (Male_Bool) == True:
        print("There was a man named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("he was " + character_age + ".")
        print("He likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")
    elif(Male_Bool) == False:
        print("There was a woman named " + character_name + ", ")
        print("she was " + character_age + ".")
        print("She likes the name " + character_name + ", ")
        print("but didn't like being " + character_age + ".")

isMale()

time.sleep(10)
```